# How to suppress warnings globally in an R Script

Tags: r, warnings

I have a long R script that throws some warnings, which I can ignore.
I could use

```
suppressWarnings(expr)
```

for single statements. But how can I suppress warnings in R globally? Is there an option for this?

Answer (score 281, accepted):

You could use

```
options(warn=-1)
```

But note that turning off warning messages globally might not be a good idea.

To turn warnings back on, use

```
options(warn=0)
```

(or whatever your default is for `warn`, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32719422/2093469))

Comment: This works, but the approach of Francesco Napolitano from Sept. 22, 2015, is the safer and more globally-applicable method.

Answer (score 139):

You want `options(warn=-1)`. However, note that `warn=0` is not the safest warning level and it should not be assumed as the current one, particularly within scripts or functions. Thus the safest way to temporary turn off warnings is:

```
oldw <- getOption("warn")
options(warn = -1)

[your "silenced" code]

options(warn = oldw)
```

Comment: Better than the accepted answer IMHO. If used in functions, replace the last line with  `on.exit(options(warn = oldw))` to ensure resetting the options regardless of errors.

Comment: `options` invisibly returns the previous values of the options changed. So you could simply do `oldw <- options(warn = -1)` and then to reset it `options(oldw)`.

Answer (score 74):

I have replaced the `printf` calls with calls to `warning` in the C-code now. It will be effective in the version 2.17.2 which should be available tomorrow night. Then you should be able to avoid the warnings with `suppressWarnings()` or any of the other above mentioned methods.

```
suppressWarnings({ your code })
```

Comment: this is the correct way to do it. Should be marked as the answer.

Answer (score 8):

Have a look at `?options` and use `warn`:

```
options( warn = -1 )
```

Answer (score 3):

As discussed in other answers, you probably want to set options(warn = -1) and revert to the old behavior. The `withr` packages allows you to set an option value and automatically revert to the old behavior.

```
# install.packages("withr")

withr::with_options(.new = list(warn = -1),
                    {code})
```

Alternatively, the `local_*` functions have the same effect until the end of the function they are included in.

```
function() {
  withr::local_options(.new = list(warn = -1)

  { code }
}
```