# How to hide warning messages from self-written function in R?

Tags: r, warnings

I am running an ordinary R script in which I have a self-written function. The function makes use of `rm()` which often produces warnings I do not want to appear in console output. Any of these solutions:

1. hiding warnings from `rm` usage from this particular self-written function,
2. hiding warnings from all usages of `rm` (globally for an R session)

would satisfy me.

```
foo.function <- function(){
  rm(foo.object)
  print("foo")
}

foo.function()
# [1] "foo"
# Warning message:
# In rm(foo.object) : object 'foo.object' not found
```

Comment: Did you try using `suppressWarnings()`?

Comment: Of course I did not :( That is correct, thank you!

Comment: You could do something like `if( length(ls(pattern = 'foo.object')) == 1 ) rm(foo.object)`.

Comment: That is correct too, however the `suppressWarnings()` is more convenient for me as I have more than one object to be (potentially) removed.

Comment: `suppressMessages()` can also be useful at times, as can the (ill-advised) global suppression `options(warn=-1)`. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16194212/how-to-suppress-warnings-globally-in-an-r-script

Comment: it might be better to `tryCatch` warnings that you _expect_ and print those that maybe you have overlooked or dont foresee. or suppresswarnings if you dont care

Answer (score 3):

For these particular case of object not found, you may use something like this:

```
if(exists("foo.object")) rm(foo.object)
```

If you want to hide other warnings as well, just use suppressWarnings().