# How to silence No encoding supplied: defaulting to UTF-8 message?

Tags: r, error-handling, httr

I'm using httr package in a function. I'd like to silence the message and run the code again if the message *No encoding supplied: defaulting to UTF-8.* is received.

I tried

```
 try(getDatafunction,silent=TRUE)
```

But it still shows the message. Is there a way to avoid it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Perhaps this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16194212/how-to-suppress-warnings-globally-in-an-r-script. It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. It's unclear exactly what the `getDatafunction` does.

Comment: Thanks a lot! suppressmessages solves the problem.