# How to remove warnings in sqldf when using update, delete or alter table

Tags: r, sqlite, rstudio, sqldf

Below is a reproducible example with warnings. I have done some research and some say that RSQLITE version causes this but not sure which version, so is there any way to prevent these warnings in sqldf.  Thanks in advance

```
(mt <- mtcars[1:5,1:5])
sqldf(c('update mt set cyl=5 where cyl>5', 'select * from mt'))
```

Warning message:
In result_fetch(res@ptr, n = n) :
  SQL statements must be issued with dbExecute() or dbSendStatement() instead of dbGetQuery() or dbSendQuery().

Comment: You might like to add your voice to this issue: https://github.com/r-dbi/RSQLite/issues/227

Answer (score 0):

You can suppress warnings globally and then reset after your code has run:

[How to suppress warnings globally in an R Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16194212/how-to-suppress-warnings-globally-in-an-r-script)

This appears to work:

```
oldw <- getOption("warn")
options(warn = -1)
(mt <- mtcars[1:5,1:5])
sqldf(c('update mt set cyl=5 where cyl>5', 'select * from mt'))
options(warn = oldw)
```

Answer (score 0):

This wrapper muffles that particular warning without interfering with others.

```
sqldf2 <- function(...) {
  withCallingHandlers(sqldf(...), warning = 
    function(w) if (grepl("SQL statements must be issued with dbExecute", w)) 
      invokeRestart("muffleWarning") else w)
}

sql <- c("update BOD set Time = 1 where Time = 2", "select * from BOD")
sqldf2(sql)
```

giving the following with no warning:

```
  Time demand
1    1    8.3
2    1   10.3  <-- Time was updated from 2 to 1 on this line
3    3   19.0
4    4   16.0
5    5   15.6
6    7   19.8
```