# supress error message of download.file function

Tags: r, error-handling, r-markdown

I want to supress an error message of `download.file` function in an Rmarkdown document. I tried `results="hide",message=F,echo=F`, i tried `invisible`, `sink`,  `suppressWarnings`,`suppressMessages`,`options(error = expression(NULL))`, without luck.
Here is my example:

````
```{r,results="hide",message=F,echo=F}

tryCatch(download.file(paste0("https://www.kjqhfkpuc.es"),
                destfile = paste0("report.pdf"),mode = "wb",quiet = T),error = function(e) e)


```
````

I want no output in my document

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `options(warn = -1)` to the start of your code chunk will suppress the warnings globally. However it is usally a good idea to turn warnings back on afterwards with your previous warning setting.

````
```{r,results="hide",message=F,echo=F}

oldw <- getOption("warn")
options(warn = -1)
tryCatch(download.file(paste0("https://www.kjqhfkpuc.es"),
            destfile = paste0("report.pdf"),mode = "wb",quiet = T),error = function(e) e)

options(warn = oldw)

```
````

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16194212/how-to-suppress-warnings-globally-in-an-r-script)