# libstableR library unwanted output

Tags: r, sweave

I'm using `libstableR` library to calculate some estimators and function `stable_fit_mle` outputs some messages while running, namely tons of `Minimizer warning: No error` and occasionally also: `FINAL ESTIMATED PARAMETER ARE NOT VALID: No error`.

I managed to suppress those messages in my final document (compiled with R Sweave) with `invisible(capture.output(...))` but those still clutter my console during compilation. Is there any way to stop those messages from appearing in the first place?

My main concern is to understand why `stable_fit_mle` is outputing these warnings (in oppose to similrar functions from `libstableR` package) and how to prevent this behaviour.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to suppress warnings globally in an R Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16194212/how-to-suppress-warnings-globally-in-an-r-script)

Comment: Not really. That's a way to hide warnings in output (console/document), which I already done (this one is simpler, though, so thanks). But we are talking about RStudio's compiler console. So I would like to get rid of the problem at the root.