# How to suppress warnings globally in a R package function

Tags: r, suppress-warnings

This is an update to an old question, [How to suppress warnings globally in an R Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16194212/how-to-suppress-warnings-globally-in-an-r-script)

where the solution was like using

```
    warn <- options(warn=-1)
    on.exit(options(warn))
```

But now CRAN says that `options(warn=-1)` is not allowed and says to use `suppressWarnings()` instead. My package was rejected because of this.
But that doesn't work globally.  What can be done?

Comment: I think this (i.e. globally changing warning behaviour when your package is loaded) is simply against CRAN rules (this would probably fall under " Packages should not modify the global environment (user’s workspace). "). Can you say more about your use case to help us help you? Why are you doing this? Do you want to suppress warnings *emanating from your package functions*?

Comment: PS I agree that the solution you've posted is reasonable (it will suppress warnings only for the duration of the function call), but if CRAN doesn't like it, you'll have to find another way to achieve what you want. It will probably be harder to implement/we need more information about your use case and goals.

Comment: Where exactly did you put those two lines of code? Did you put them in a function? Or did you have them as a top-level statement in your package?

Comment: These lines of code are in a function, that calls `chol()` for a Cholesky decomposition in a context where I need to allow for the fact that the matrix may be singular.  This is used in my {gellipsoid} package, https://github.com/friendly/gellipsoid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could put the entire body of your function inside a `suppressWarnings()` block, e.g.

```r
foo <- function(a,b,c) {
  ret_values <- suppressWarnings({
    ## body of the function goes here
  })
  return(ret_values)
}
```

This is is a hack (among other things, it will make source-level debugging harder), the original `options()/on.exit(options(...))` solution is better, but if CRAN doesn't like it you're stuck.

If you just want to prevent a **particular** function call from issuing a warning (according to your comments above,  it's `chol()` in your case), then `suppressWarnings(chol(...))` should work, and should be better than the brute-force solution suggested above (based on [this commit](https://github.com/friendly/gellipsoid/commit/2759d4880502983d0e2242a9d4cdac42f018ec76) it looks like you've already implemented this ...)

It would be even better to be able to trap only *specific* warnings: e.g. `sqrt(-1)` and `sqrt(10000000000000000000000L)` return different warnings, one might want to trap the "NaNs produced" warning and not the "non-integer value qualified with L" warning. Unfortunately for reasons [explained on the r-devel mailing list in 2012](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2012-October/065089.html) (i.e., warning messages may be translated so you can't use text-matching on the message), there's (AFAIK) no reliable way to do this.

Comment: OK, this is a general solution, but IMHO far to draconian. My solution is to just trap the call to `chol()`.

Comment: I agree. But since you didn't provide your use case (i.e. I didn't know there was a single point at which you were trying to trap warnings), I gave the general solution.

Answer (score 0):

In my use case, the solution is just to trap the call to `chol()` that will give warnings.

```
ellipsoid <- function(center, 
                      shape, 
                      radius=1, 
                      segments=60, 
                      warn.rank=FALSE){

    # adapted from the shapes3d demo in the rgl package and from the Rcmdr package
    degvec <- seq(0, 2*pi, length=segments)
    ecoord2 <- function(p) c(cos(p[1])*sin(p[2]), 
                             sin(p[1])*sin(p[2]), 
                             cos(p[2]))
    v <- t(apply(expand.grid(degvec,degvec), 1, ecoord2))
    # if (!warn.rank){
    #   warn <- options(warn=-1)
    #   on.exit(options(warn))
    # }
    if (warn.rank) {
    Q <- chol(shape, pivot=TRUE)
    }
    else {
      Q <- suppressWarnings(chol(shape, pivot=TRUE))
    }
    order <- order(attr(Q, "pivot"))
    v <- center + radius * t(v %*% Q[, order])
    v <- rbind(v, rep(1,ncol(v))) 
    e <- expand.grid(1:(segments-1), 1:segments)
    i1 <- apply(e, 1, function(z) z[1] + segments*(z[2] - 1))
    i2 <- i1 + 1
    i3 <- (i1 + segments - 1) %% segments^2 + 1
    i4 <- (i2 + segments - 1) %% segments^2 + 1
    i <- rbind(i1, i2, i4, i3)
    x <- asEuclidean(t(v))
    ellips <- qmesh3d(v, i)
    return(ellips)
}
```

Comment: the answer might be clearer if you excerpted just the `if (warn.rank) { ... } else {...}` part.