# Warning: replacing previous import 'DT::dataTableOutput' by 'shiny::dataTableOutput'

Tags: r, shiny, render, dt

I am building a package based on shiny and I get the following error message:

```
Warning: replacing previous import ‘DT::dataTableOutput’ by ‘shiny::dataTableOutput’ when loading ‘StatisticTeach1’
     Warning: replacing previous import ‘DT::renderDataTable’ by ‘shiny::renderDataTable’ when loading ‘StatisticTeach1’
```

Although I make the suggested changes the problem persist

Comment: It will be easier to help you if you provide a reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: This is a warning message, not an error message.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/71927778/5221626

Comment: From [here](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/shiny.html): Note that in `DT`, `DTOutput()` is an alias of `dataTableOutput()`, and `renderDT()` is an alias of `renderDataTable()`. You are recommended to use `DTOutput()` and `renderDT()` to avoid possible collisions with functions of the same names in `shin`y (`shiny::dataTableOutput()` and `shiny::renderDataTable()`).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following namespace

```
#' @rawNamespace import(shiny, except=c(dataTableOutput, renderDataTable))
```