# Suppress messages in console when running shiny

Tags: r, shiny

See example:

```
shinyFunction <- function(){
  shinyApp(
    ui = basicPage(
      actionButton('print_message', "Print a message")
    ),
    
    server = function(input, output){
      observeEvent(input$print_message, {
        message("Here is a message")
      })
    } 
  ) 
}
```

The app prints a message to the console on-click.

How do I suppress this behavior?

Wrapping it with
`suppressMessages(shinyFunction())` does not work...

I don't want the console to print ANYTHING. How can I achieve this?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: You can wrap your code within `suppressWarnings`, `suppressMessages`. Alternatively you can follow  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16194212/how-to-suppress-warnings-globally-in-an-r-script).

Answer (score 0):

There are many things that you can do here. As you rightly said, `suppressWarnings()` and `suppressMessages()` can be used in this case which will not print anything on the console. Alternatively, you can use the `showNotification()` function to show notifications in shiny app.
https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/notifications.html

```
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    actionButton("show", "Show")
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    observeEvent(input$show, {
      showNotification("This is a notification.")
    })
  }
)
```

However, if you want to print attractive messages for the console, you can use the `cli` package in R.

```
cli::cli_alert_warning("This is a warning message")
# ! This is a warning message

cli::cli_alert_success("This is a success message")
# √ This is a success message
```

One more solution I would like to suggest here is to print the output or any messages in a log file and not on console.

Keep Coding!