# How do I silence this particular R message?

Tags: r

I am running an R function within a third-party software package. (The third-party package uses an older version of R, version 3.6). The output I am passing along is:

```
library(tidyverse)
theOutput <- x %>%
  left_join(y, by = "id")
```

However, the output I am getting from the package is this notification, which I see in RStudio whenever I do a join, `Joining, by = "id"`. How do I silence this message such that it will not be passed along as output? I tried

```
options(tidyverse.quiet = TRUE)
```

but it does not seem to stop the join message.

(Also, if the only answer is "your third party needs to use the newest version of R," I understand, but that is unfortunately impossible.)

Comment: Does this help, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16194212/how-to-suppress-warnings-globally-in-an-r-script

Comment: Unfortunately not. The Join notification does not appear to be considered a "warning."

Comment: swap out "warning" with "message", and it should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `suppressMessages`. First, let's recreate your issue:

```r
library(dplyr)

df1 <- data.frame(letter = c("A", "B", "C"), data  = 1:3)
df2 <- data.frame(letter = c("A", "B", "C"), value = 4:6)

df1 %>%
  left_join(df2)
#> Joining, by = "letter"
#>   letter data value
#> 1      A    1     4
#> 2      B    2     5
#> 3      C    3     6
```

Note we have the "Joining, by" message. But if we add `suppressMessages` to the pipe after our left join

```r
df1 %>% 
  left_join(df2) %>%
  suppressMessages()
#>   letter data value
#> 1      A    1     4
#> 2      B    2     5
#> 3      C    3     6
```

It disappears.

<sup>Created on 2022-09-15 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: this worked as desired. Thanks very much.

Comment: Another way to suppress all messages is `options(rlib_message_verbosity = "quiet")`.

Comment: @user2554330 that's a good tip, though for safety it's usually better to handle specific messages you know you want to ignore.