Suprress warnings in Rstudio console in Quarto Document
Some code I am working generates a very long but very irrelevant warning in one code chunk in a Quarto document.

I have set warning: false in the global options and so in the actual Quarto document, the warning is suppressed.  But I m working on this code iteratively, running the code chunks in the Quarto document by clicking on the run all chunks above button to get caught up and then develop the code from there.
When I go up to the problematic code chunk and add a supplementary warning: false to the chunk itself, it works, but why does the global warning: false not accomplish this?
How do I suppress the warnings in the output of the Quarto source code editor?
---
title: "Test"
format: html

execute: 
  warning: false
  message: false
  echo: false
---



## Running Code

When you click the **Render** button a document will be generated that includes both content and the output of embedded code. You can embed code like this:

```{r}
warning()
warning()
warning()
warning()
warning()
```

```{r}
print("Hello")
```


That YAML header only affects how the document behaves when running the document through Quarto. When you run code chunks in your editor, Quarto isn't involved at all. It's like you are just copy/pasting code from the document into your console. Check out more general ways to suppress warnings in this existing question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16194212/how-to-suppress-warnings-globally-in-an-r-script

OK that is a helpful explanation. I think adding the warning: false to the chunk on its own is best for my purposes. I like having warnings; just not when they are debilitatingly long.
Thank you.
